# Accessing dynamically created Variables set in a for loop

Tags: python-3.x, dynamic, wxpython

TLDR FIX: put your objects(or list of objects) into a dictionary

Simply put, i am creating a bunch of pages in a wxpython notebook dynamically and on each page i am placing further widgets and sizers and such. my issue is that if i want to access a variable set in the for loop when it creates the page, i am unable to because once the for loops runs again the variable will be reset and used to populate the new page.

something along the lines of this

```
class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
    kwds["style"] = kwds.get("style", 0) | wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE
    wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwds)
    self.SetSize((400, 300))
    self.notebook_1 = wx.Notebook(self, wx.ID_ANY)
    self.text_button = wx.Button(self, wx.ID_ANY, "get text")
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.get_text_handler, self.text_button)

    self.__set_properties()

    sizer_1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    sizer_2 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
    sizer_1.Add(self.text_button, 0, 0, 0)
    sizer_1.Add(self.notebook_1, 1, wx.EXPAND, 0)
    self.SetSizer(sizer_1)
    self.Layout()
    numlist = (1, 2, 3, 4)
    #global page_dictionary
    #page_dictionary = {}
    for i in numlist:
        self.notebook_1_pane_2 = wx.Panel(self.notebook_1, wx.ID_ANY)
        self.notebook_1_pane_2.SetSizer(sizer_2)
        self.notebook_1.AddPage(self.notebook_1_pane_2, str(i))
        self.label_1 = wx.TextCtrl(self.notebook_1_pane_2, wx.ID_ANY, str(i))
        sizer_2.Add(self.label_1, 0, 0, 0)
        self.Layout()
        #page_k = self.label_1.GetValue()
        #page_k_good = page_k + str(i)
        #page_dictionary[page_k_good] = i
        #print(page_dictionary)

def __set_properties(self):
    self.SetTitle("frame")

def get_text_handler(self, event):  # wxGlade: MyFrame.<event_handler>
    print(self.label_1.GetValue())
```

the only difference between this and what im actually running, is that the numlist variable is actually generating a random number of values dynamically

my issue is that if i want to reference any of the labels ive set in previous pages, i can't because the self.label_1 variable gets reset to the entry on the last page. so if i want to access the label on say page number 1 the label variable is set to the values of the last page created in the for loop. its like once the label is placed and populated on the wxNotebook page its just gone and what is in that widget isn't accessible anymore.

so how would i, say for example, print(self.label_1) of page 1 in the notebook when self.label_1 was rewritten to match the label in the last page generated?

was messing around with dictionaries so i commented that out.
how would i be able to click that button, and have it get the text from the boxes in current pages?

Final edit hopefully:

how would i go about assigning multiple objects into the dictionary? would i need to just assign the value i as a list (label_1, Label_2) then when needing to call methods on them just reference them from the list, that is now in the dictionary?

yup, that did it, put them into the dictionary as a list, can pull the list when needed.

Comment: Based on what I think you are saying you are creating a series of pages dynamically in a notebook using a for loop.  On each page you are placing a number of widgets.  Your problem is that after you have completed the loop for a specific page, you can no longer reference that page's contents because number now references a different page..  Please edit your question to show a minimal reproducible set.  See [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") for details on how to best help us help you.

Comment: This is the first time i've ever messed with something like this and i have no clue how to even begin to go about it. is there a way to add the variable i to the variable names on generation? so self.label_1 would become self.label_1(i) and end up as self.label_11, self.label_12, self.label13 etc, that way i could reference them easily after generation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am still at a loss as to exactly what you are trying to do, but based on an educated guess  I think you are trying to preserve the identity of objects created in a loop so that they maybe accessed outside of the loop.  With this in mind, here is an example of how this can be done.  Here is a very simplistic example:

```
import random as rnd  #used to create a random number for each object

# just a list of names to be scanned in for loop
lst = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]

# Just an illustrative object for demo purposes
class SillyClass:
    def __init__(self, name, nmb):
        self._id = name
        self._nmb = nmb
        
    @property
    def name(self):
        return self._id
    
    @property
    def number(self):
        return self._nmb
      
# create a list of objects for later reference
def build_objects(lst):
    rslt = []
    for itm in lst:
        rslt.append(SillyClass(itm, rnd.randrange(5, 200)))
    return rslt  

# show use of list to print object data
obj_lst = build_objects(lst)

# Show the contents of obj_lst
print(obj_lst, "\n")

# show access of object attributes
for obj in obj_lst:
    print(f"Object: {obj.name} contains {obj.number}")
```

The result of running this code is:

```
[<__main__.SillyClass object at 0x0000022C5CB9E9D0>, <__main__.SillyClass object at 0x0000022C5CB9EFD0>, <__main__.SillyClass object at 0x0000022C5CB9E670>, <__main__.SillyClass object at 0x0000022C5CC42370>] 

Object: a contains 187
Object: b contains 164
Object: c contains 97
Object: d contains 52
```

This illustrates that obj_lst contains a list of objects, which then can be used to access the attributes of the object.  You can utilize this approach or possibly associate the object to a specific identifier using a dict structure.  What ever you need to best serve your purposes.

Comment: basically im assigning a textctrl to every page of a notebook in wxpython, but i can't return what is currently in those textctrls because the variable they are assigned to is getting replaced everytime the loop repeats. is it even possible to interact with a widget on a notebook page that was created dynamically or is this just a crazy concept

Comment: i have updated the code with the textctrls i was talking about

Comment: If you want to access the widgets create a dictionary where the key is a variable name or just an integer and the value is the widget object created.  Example:   ```{1:widget_object1, 2:widget_object2, . . . .}```

Comment: In your loop replace ```page_dictionary[page_k_good] = i``` with ```page_dictionary[i] = self.label_1```  Now page_dictionary contains each of the defined self_label_1's indexed by page index.

Comment: sweet, my final question is how im going to access those objects for information, can you call methods on objects that are in a dictionary?

Comment: sure you can.  For example, let's say you want the value of the self.label_1 widget on page 4, you would simply execute the following:  ```v = page_dictionary[4].GetValue()```

Comment: That is awesome! man, oop is soo much more efficient. what if there are more than one objects getting created in the loop tho? label_1 AND label_2

Comment: what if there are more than one objects getting created in the loop tho? label_1 AND label_2? im not sure how to go about adding them to the dictionary, can't use just dictionary[i] = label_1 because you also need to add label_2

Comment: create a list of widgets to be added to the page then the dictionary value for the page is simply the list of widgets.  You can then access each widget based on its order in the list.

Comment: YUP, got it all sorted and working now, THANKS A TON! this is my first venture into OOP and i legit didn't know you could just store entire objects in list(and then into subsequent dictionaries). total game changer

Comment: oops, see you already did.  Glad to have helped.